# Mongo aggregate $group _id is an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `$group` pipeline in my aggregate :

`{$group: {_id: '$user.username'}}`

Where `user.username` is a string, but in my result, the `_id` field is actually an array containing the string, why?

Comment: Because `$user` itself is an array.

Comment: @NeilLunn $user is an object

Comment: If you see anything like `_id: ["something"]` from your statement in the question `"user"` is not an `Object`. It only looks like that when it's an `Array`, and that's where you use `$unwind` first.

Comment: @NeilLunn I see, I was getting the `$user` from a `$lookup`, which is returning an array and not an Object. Your comment was more helpful than the duplicate tag link, maybe you could answer directly and I will accept